# Como especiar a sequência de activities a serem iniciadas?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Olá.
Estou com uma dúvida. Tenho um APP no qual 8 Activities, entre elas possui uma Splash Screen Activity que apresenta a minha logo e depois entra no meu APP.

A Splash Screen está definida como padrão, mas preciso definir uma outra Activity como sendo sencudária para ser iniciada após a tela que possui a logo, pois está iniciando outra Activity que não é a tela inicial do App.
Como poderia realizar esse procedimento?

Segue o meu AndroidManifes.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main"/>
        <activity android:name=".ContraDenuncia" />
        <activity android:name=".FavorDenuncia" />
        <activity android:name=".Investigados" />
        <activity android:name=".Objetivo" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Preciso que a Activity Main seja executada após a SplashScreenActivity.

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá que fazer a sua outra activity ser startada após a execução da sua splash. Mas antes disso, coloque a `<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">` como primeira no manifest. Após isso vá no código da sua splash, e após terminar de executar a splash, coloque isso

```
    Intent it = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(it);
```

Na definição do intenent, você está especificando digamos, "de onde para onde" e o método startActivity() é para começar a atividade definida no Intent

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Funcionou belezinha.

Comment: Boa, precisar tamos ae =)